# How to check if touch point is on UIBezierPath (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, touch, uibezierpath

How could I know if a touch point (touchesBegan) is on a hidden UIBezierPath?

Comment: documentation is your friend: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276-CH1-SW40

Comment: I allways need some sample code to understand. :-/ so documentation is cool, but not my best frriend...

Comment: You're right - i think most of us can relate to that :) feel free to leave me a message if Chris doesn't post you a sample code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[bezierPath containsPoint:touchPoint];
```

Just make sure that your touch point is in the same coordinate system as the bezierPaths points and that the points are within the same context i.e. both in screen space.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([self.bezierPath containsPoint:touchPoint])
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Also note: If you are using your UIBezierPath in some CoreGraphics drawing you will want to flip the y-axis on the touchPoint for example...

> touchPoint.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - touchPoint.y;

Comment: As new as I am to objective-c I need to ask here: could you please post me some more code? that would be so great! thank you!

Comment: I guess this is what you want... `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    
    if ([self.bezierPath containsPoint:touchPoint])
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}` That said, you should read the Apple docs and comments in framework header files... I appreciate that you are new to iOS but nobody is going to write your app for you, it doesn't help them and it doesn't help you to do so.

Comment: @ChrisHeyes: hope you don't mind i moved code from your comment to the answer.

Comment: thank you both! I will try out - but I am still afraid that the coordinate systems are different in the end as you mentioned because the MainViewController holds checks for the touches but the touchPathView is part of the MainView and lies anywhere on the screen...

Comment: All coords are based on the views... view controllers simply reference views. I think you'll want to substitute self.view for your touchPathView in the above code, assuming your bezierPath is local to that view.

Comment: great answers. at least I need to know I it will be no problem not to show the path in the view. I need the path being hidden.

Comment: unfortunately the method 'containsPoint' returns YES if the touch point is inside the border of the path and not on the stroke line only. I need a solution to find out if the touch point is on the path line only.

Comment: Reading the docs it indicates that the stroke path is tested for intersection, though I may be wrong... how wide is your stroke line?... Suggest you NSLog all the points and information about the UIBezierPath itself including it's reference points. Again, I'm not too sure about that exact behaviour as I've never implemented this myself. What is it exactly you are trying to achieve? It could be there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot! now I found out that my approach is leading in the wrong dirrection. now I try to solve the problem with a hidden mask image with a black path on white background, checking if the color of the touchpoint is black...

Comment: I was going to suggest that. If you need help with it let me know as that IS something I have implemented before