# Detecting touch point in a line

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am not able to find the touch point in the line drawn using UIBezierpath. CGPathContainPoint is not working for line. Please help me out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831370/how-to-check-if-touch-point-is-on-uibezierpath-ios    can you check this link

Answer (score 7):

You can create another path object that represents how the path actually looks on screen, then check if the touch point is inside that path. In the [CGPath reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html), you'll find the handy constructor function `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath`. You would use it somewhat like this:

```
CGPathRef originalPath = myBezierPath.CGPath;  //The single-line path

//Use the values you use to draw the path onscreen, 
//or use a width representing how far the user can touch
//for it to be recognized by the path.
//For example, for an error tolerance of 4px, use a width of 8px.
CGPathRef strokedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(originalPath, NULL, lineWidth, lineCap, lineJoin, miterLimit);
BOOL pathContainsPoint = CGPathContainsPoint(strokedPath, NULL, touchPoint, NO);
```

As shown above, this gives you the benefit of specifying a region for the user to touch instead of a line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to select a particular line from a set of shapes

Comment: What's the problem? This code just determines if one point intersects one path. To select a line from a set of paths, just loop through the paths and run this code for each of them.

Comment: @architectpianist, If I could give this 10 upvotes I would. I've been looking all over for a way to detect a point falling on a single line and this solution works perfectly. Thanks