# How to make a UIBezierPath selectable

Tags: ios, swift

Hello StackOverFlow community,

I have a standard UIBezierPath as follows:

```
let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect){

    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
    let radius: CGFloat = max(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height) - 60
    let arcWidth: CGFloat = 40

    var startAngle: CGFloat = 0
    var endAngle: CGFloat = (2 * π)      
    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
            radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
            startAngle: startAngle,
            endAngle: endAngle,
            clockwise: true)

   path.lineWidth = arcWidth
   UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
   path.stroke()
}
```

This produces a very simple Arc. Quite simply, I want to be able to select/press this arc while the application is running (like a button), and be able to trigger an action. Is there any way that this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: An example action that I would be interested in accomplishing would be like changing the text of a label if the Arc was pressed

Comment: Add a view and on top of it add the UIbezierPath. Make the view clickable using UITapGesture. In the tap function, detect if the tap was done inside the area of the bezierPath. If yes, do whatever you want to do to it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831370/how-to-check-if-touch-point-is-on-uibezierpath-ios

Comment: You can add a tap gesture to the view where the bezier path was drew. And then in the gesture selector, do some check to see if the touch point is inside the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `Outlet` for your Custom View and add `tapgesture` in that custom view like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var arcView: customView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "SomeMethod")
        self.arcView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func SomeMethod(){

        //change label text
    }
}
```

Now when ever you tap on your `arcView` your `SomeMethod` will call.And you can change your label text in that method.

For more Info refer [THIS](https://www.weheartswift.com/bezier-paths-gesture-recognizers/) tutorial where you can find how to detect touch on `Bezier Paths`.